# Strange behavior using PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I've got a class derived from PhoneStateListener and when its called with CALL_STATE_RINGING I cache the incoming number.

I have noticed that sometimes the listener is called twice with CALL_STATE_RINGING for the same incoming number.

What is puzzling me is when the listener is called twice the value of my cached incoming number is null. Here's the abbreviated code to illustrate:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public  String                  mIncomingCallId;
    private TelephonyManager        mTelephonyMgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        mTelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Incoming number: " + incomingNumber + " mIncomingCallId: " + mIncomingCallId);
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.i(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
                    if (mIncomingCallId == null)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "setting mIncomingCallId to: " + incomingNumber);
                        mIncomingCallId = incomingNumber;
```

When executed I see this in the log:

```
Incoming number: 2067958520 mIncomingCallId: null
CALL_STATE_RINGING  
setting mIncomingCallId to: 2067958520 onCallStateChanged. 
Incoming number: 2067958520 mIncomingCallId: null  
CALL_STATE_RINGING
```

How can mIncomingCallId be null the second time onCallStateChanged() is invoked when it was set to the incoming number the first onCallStateChanged() was called?

mIncomingCallId is not being set to null elsewhere in the code before onCallStateChanged() gets called for the second time.

onCreate() is only being called called once.

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint in the listener then examine the variables and step through your code to see what's happening?

Comment: Two invocations to the listener with CALL_STATE_RINGING only happens very occasionally so its not something I can reproduce at will in the debugger. I've obviously stepped through the code when there's one invocation of CALL_STATE_RINGING and everything is fine, I've done a code review and everything is fine. When it does do this its almost as if sometimes there are two instances of the TeleListener.

Comment: My wild guess is: You don't seem to store Activity data, so while device is handling incoming call it moves to onPause() state - other (Caller) activity is launched on top of Yours. After it vanishes, Your activity doesn't use onCreate() but onStart() (recovering from pause)

Comment: Why would using onStart() instead of onCreate() cause a problem?